# Java installation error using apt-cacher

Tags: java, apt-cacher

I'm getting this output when I trey to update/install oracle-java7 or from webupd8 ppa:

```
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2014-11-19 16:35:02--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u72-b14/jdk-7u72-    linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving debiancacherepo.domain.com (debiancacherepo.domain.com)... 192.168.130.129
Connecting to debiancacherepo.domain.com (debiancacherepo.domain.com)|192.168.130.129|:3142... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 403 Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: jdk-7u72-linux-x64.tar.gz
2014-11-19 16:35:02 ERROR 403: Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: jdk-7u72-linux-x64.tar.gz.

download failed
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
```

My `/etc/apt-cacher.conf`

```
#package_files_regexp = (?:^[-+.a-z0-9]+_(?:\d:)?[-+.~a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:_?[-a-z0-9]+\.(?:u|d)?    deb|\.dsc|\.tar(?:\.gz|\.bz2|\.xz)|\.diff\.gz)|\.rpm|index\.db-.+\.gz|\.jigdo|\.template)$

#pdiff_files_regexp = ^2\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}\.\d{2}\.gz$

#index_files_regexp = ^(?:Index(?:\.bz2)?|(?:Sources|Packages|release)(?:\.gz|\.bz2)?|Release(?:\.gpg)?|InRelease|Contents-(?:[a-z]+-)?[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.gz|(?:srclist|pkglist)\.[a-z-    ]+\.bz2|Translation-[a-z]{2,3}(?:_[A-Z]{2}(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-$
```

I think apt-cacher doesn't like the format of the file **jdk-7u72-linux-x64.tar.gz** but I am not able to change the configuration to allow it.

Answer (score 6):

Ok, finally I've found a solution in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195297/install-oracle-java7-installer-through-apt-cacher-ng) post.

Adding

```
Acquire::http::Proxy { download.oracle.com DIRECT; };
```

in the proxy configuration /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy.