# ERROR 403: Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz in 14.04

Tags: apt, java, ppa, downloads

I have had oracle's jdk7 installed on my `64bit Ubuntu 14.04` now for some time and it has behaved as expected.

However lately all my updates has ended in errors and after some research I found the following:

```
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
```

The reason is given further up:

```
Downloading Oracle Java 7...
--2015-04-28 12:00:58--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/7u80-b15/jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving localhost (localhost)... 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:3142... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 403 Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz
2015-04-28 12:00:58 ERROR 403: Sorry, not allowed to fetch that type of file: jdk-7u80-linux-x64.tar.gz.
```

I don't really know how to fix this. I tried purging and re-intsalling but it seems that this is Oracle shutting down the download from Ubuntu users like me. The nerve!

Comment: The hint is "Proxy request sent"  see http://askubuntu.com/questions/551474/java-installation-error-using-apt-cacher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Purge all you old versions and install a latest Oracle JDK.
Just follow the steps given in this [site](http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-JDK-on-Ubuntu-Linux) to install JDK